# Can't get the value by key from request.session; I use django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do online shop with django. But i got some problem. During making the cart I'm getting the error 'local variable 'cart_id' referenced before assignment' in views.py. 
Here is this file:

```
def cart_view(request):
    try:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        request.session['total'] = cart.items.count()
    except:
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        cart_id = cart_id
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cart.html', locals())
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\ecomapp\views.py" in product_view
  13.       cart_id = request.session['cart_id']

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in __getitem__
  54.         return self._session[key]

During handling of the above exception ('cart_id'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop\ecomapp\views.py" in product_view
  19.       cart_id = cart_id

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /product/macbook-pro/
Exception Value: local variable 'cart_id' referenced before assignment
```

Then I tried to solve it by adding `global cart_id` to function cart_view and got another error: name 'cart_id' is not defined.
Here is new traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\ecomapp\views.py" in product_view
  14.       cart_id = request.session['cart_id']

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in __getitem__
  54.         return self._session[key]

During handling of the above exception ('cart_id'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\eComEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tankr\Django_projects\django_shop_2\ecomapp\views.py" in product_view
  20.       cart_id = cart_id

Exception Type: NameError at /product/iphone-xr-128gb/
Exception Value: name 'cart_id' is not defined
```

Comment: can post your url which calls this `cart_view`?

Comment: Thanks it is already solved. It was cart_id = cart.id line. I didn't saw my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line <s>`cart_id = cart_id`</s> makes no sense, you want to use `cart.id` I think, or even safer `cart.pk`:

```
def cart_view(request):
    try:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
    except (KeyError, Cart.DoesNotExist):
        cart = Cart.objects.create()
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id = cart.pk
        request.session['total'] = 0
    else:
        request.session['total'] = cart.items.count()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cart.html', locals())
```

Please do *not* use `locals()` however. From a software design point of view, it is not good practice. It does mean you do *not* know what you pass to the template. If you would acidentally create a variable that has the same name as that of a variable from a context-processor, you might get un-intended behavior.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you so much. I thought that I had written cart_id = cart.id. It's all my inattentiveness

Comment: Understood, but then where we shound use locals()?

Comment: @Shakhzoda: you can create a dictionary like `{'cart_id': cart_id, 'cart': cart}` (including all variables you need).

Comment: Could you please explain me what is pk. I has read about it, but still can not understad what is it and where I shoud use it?

Comment: @Shakhzoda: `pk` is just the primary key. Normally the primary key is named `id`, but it can be named differently. By using `pk`, we ensure that we always use the primary key, even if you later decide to change the primary key to a field that is *not* named `id`.

Comment: I know that I can create a dictionary. In last projects I used it, but recently I saw locals function and started to use this. I ask you where I shoud use locals, not a dictionary?

Comment: @Shakhzoda: only if you can not derive what the local variables are and you need all the local variables. As the *Zen of Python* says: "*explicit over implicit*". By using `locals()` it is not clear what you pass to the template (and what not). That means that if you would rename a local variable (usually an operation that people consider safe), it can break your code. See for example: http://www.paulbutcher.space/blog/2018/01/10/python-locals

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your try block is not executing and execept block start executing where `cart_id = cart_id` is present and this is why you are getting error.

you can do something like this in your existing code

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart_id = request.session['cart_id']                     # before try block
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        request.session['total'] = cart.items.count()
    except:
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        cart_id = cart_id
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cart.html', locals())
```

Comment: I think the problem is that not all `request.session`s have *per se* a `cart_id` at all time.